# Error: Cannot find the jsonl: gs://{bucket_name}/Frist_test.jsonl in request

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl, google-natural-language

I am exploring using Google Cloud Platform Natural Language for entity extraction. I am working on just setting up a playground to get the hang of things and I can't seem to get past square one.  I have created a new cloud store bucket to hold my project file.

I made a simple csv file to point to a one line jsonl file. But I am missing something in the address to my cloud bucket stored file.

My csv looks like this:
Train, gs://new_wc_training/Frist_test.jsonl

And my jsonl file looks like this:
{"text_snippet":{"content": "This is a first test of my json file."}}

When I import my csv file I get the error:
Error: Cannot find the jsonl: gs://new_wc_training/Frist_test.jsonl in request.

I am sure I am just missing something in the structure of the address to the jsonl file in the bucket, but I am at a loss as to finding it.

Thank you for looking over my issue and if there is any additional information needed do not hesitate in asking.

Comment: I was able to replicate your error when I misspelled the jsonl file. Can you check the jsonl file if it matches the actual saved file in your bucket?  You can list the files saved in your bucket by executing `gsutil ls gs://new_wc_training/`. Can you edit your post and include the contents of your bucket?

Comment: When I replicated your issue, the jsonl file in the bucket is saved as **First**_test.jsonl. The jsonl file indicated in the csv file is **Frist**_test.jsonl which does not match the actual file in the bucket.

Comment: That was 100% my issue. Thank you again!

Comment: I posted this as the answer for reference :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per discussion with @fred_rogers, the problem is that the JSONL filename declared inside the CSV file does not match with the actual filename in the bucket.

The fix is to match the JSONL filename in the bucket and in the CSV file.